# Constructing an orthogonal polynomial regression model

Tags: regression, polynomial

My current model is:

> $$y_i = a_0 +a_1x_i + a_2x_i^2 + \epsilon_i $$

With $E[\epsilon_i] = 0, Var[\epsilon_i] = \sigma^2$.

I have the information:

> $$\begin{matrix} i & \mathrm{Response} \, y_i & \mathrm{Covariate} \, x_i \\ 1 & -1 & -0.5 \\ 2 & -0.25 &-0.25 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 4 & 1.2 & 0.25 \\ 5 & 2.6 & 0.5 \end{matrix}$$

I need to propose an orthogonal polynomial regression model of the same order as my current one.

So I thought that if I let $\zeta_1$ be the linear terms and $\zeta_2$ be the quadratic terms, then I want a model where $\sum \zeta_1 = \sum \zeta_2 = 0$. So I want two general forms of $\zeta$. So let us let:

$$\zeta_1 = a + bx_i$$
$$\zeta_2 = a + bx_i + cx_i^2$$

Now I want to solve for $a,b,c$.

But I'm stuck on how to solve for them. I can't just use normal simultaneous equations from here can I because everything cancels out leaving me with everything equal to $0$. What do I do?

Comment: (This reminds me of the legend about the only lock Houdini failed to pick: it was unlocked all the time!) In this case, your vectors $\textbf 1 = (1,1,1,1,1)$, $\textbf x=(-1/2,-1/4,0,1/4,1/2)$, and $\textbf x^2=(1/4,1/16,0,1/16,1/4)$ are almost orthogonal already, as you can readily check, so there's not much left to do. You only need to make $\textbf x^2$ orthogonal to $\textbf 1$ by subtracting some multiple of $\textbf 1$ from it.

Comment: Could I put it in a matrix and do some kind of matrix reduction to make the two vectors orthogonal, and this row operation is what I subtract from $I$ to get my new thingy?

Comment: You can use a matrix to simplify the notation, but there's no need. You just need to find the multiple $\lambda$ for which the inner product of $\textbf{x}^2 - \lambda\textbf{1}$ with $\textbf{1}$ is zero. When you do the calculations--which are so easy they can be done by inspection--the equation is of the form $a - b\lambda=0$, which is simple to solve. This is an example of [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).